# How do I send telnetlib control + c command in python

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

I am trying to send control + c command in python using telnetlib library. Currently I am doing

```
tn.write('^]')
```

But the code above doesn't seem to work. Any clue on What I should use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [ASCII characters](http://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html#cntrl) of `control+c`  to the telnet connection below:-

```
tn.write('\x03')
```

Answer (score 6):

```
ctrl+a = decimal 1
ctrl+b = decimal 2
ctrl+c = decimal 3
```

and so on.. to

```
ctrl+x = decimal 24
ctrl+y = decimal 25
ctrl+z = decimal 26

escape = 27 etc
```

Still, for those who will need this in the future

Arrow keys are (3 bytes, decimal)

```
UP ARROW is 27,91,65 (ESC,'[',A)
DOWN ARROW is 27,91,66 (ESC,'[',B)
RIGHT ARROW is 27,91,67 (ESC, '[',C)
LEFT ARROW is 27,91,68 (ESC, '[',D)
```