# how do I press arrow keys in telnet using telnetlib

Tags: python-3.x

I can press keys or send text using following method:

```
tn.write(b"4\n")
```

How would I do it for UP, DOWN and other arrow keys?

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [How do I send telnetlib control + c command in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183298/how-do-i-send-telnetlib-control-c-command-in-python)

following worked for me:

```
# up
tn.write(b"\x1B\x5B\x41\n")

# down
tn.write(b"\x1B\x5B\x42\n")

# left
tn.write(b"\x1B\x5B\x43\n")

# right
tn.write(b"\x1B\x5B\x44\n")
```